# Blackberry - How to do text wrapping in ListField with Checkboxes?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, custom-controls, word-wrap, listfield

I m creating a ListField with Checkboxes from  [How To - Create a ListField with check boxes](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800345/How_To_-_Create_a_ListField_with_check_boxes.html?nodeid=1165752&vernum=0)
But I m not getting how to wrap Text in a row in that ListField.
I referred the thread
[Text Wrapping for text in List Field items](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Text-Wrapping-for-text-in-List-Field-items/td-p/232896)

Here its written as

> If all you are displaying is text, then I would go with the approach suggested by rab.

I m displaying Text only in ListField which I want to wrap if it doesnt fit within device screen.
But i m not getting "approach suggested by rab"  in which How to calculate?

> String [] linesToDraw = calculate the number of lines depending on the row width

I m stucked at this so any details on this issue ?

---

With ur logic I got

```
* split text on words
* create string array and while words array not empty do
      o create string lineStr
      o while getFont().getAdvance(lineStr+" "+words[i]) < row width move words[i] to lineStr
```

I m doing it like

```
if(getFont().getAdvance(lineStr+" "+words[i]) < Display.getWidth())
{
    lineStr += words[i];
}
```

& I m storing lineStr in a Vector linesToDraw as the same lineStr I m using for storing text of next row.

& in the end for drawing I m doing

```
for (int i = 0; i < linesToDraw.size(); i++)
{ 
          String textToDraw = (String)linesToDraw.elementAt(i);
          graphics.drawText(textToDraw, 0, y, 0, w);
          y += fontHeight;
}
```

but how to calculate no. of lines of a row & row height?

so that with this row height I can write setRowHeight(rowHeight) as the row height is different for different rows.

---

I got the no. of lines properly according to row width & stored it in a Vector & i m doing

```
int fontHeight = this.getFont().getHeight();

     for (int i = 0; i < linesToDraw .size(); i++)
    {           
        textToDraw = (String)linesToDraw.elementAt(i);
        graphics.drawText(textToDraw, xpos, ypos, 0 , width);
        ypos += fontHeight;
    }
```

now its drawing the lines but over the previous one as by default listField.setRowHeight() is taking only one row. If there r 2 rows then I write setRowHeight(getFont().getHeight()*2) in drawListRow() but then it goes in loop

If I write setRowHeight() while creating ListField then it comes properly but for all rows same row height is set.

I gets the String to draw at Runtime & the row height should be variable for different rows then how can I setRowHeight() with what parameter & in which method ?

Comment: @NullUserException Where did all that text come from that you just edited in?

Comment: @MichaelDonohue From an "answer" posted by the OP which I deleted.

Comment: @NullUserException Thanks. Looks like some new functionality of SO, as I see a number of BlackBerry questions have had this edit now.

Comment: @MichaelDonohue Well, it's been here for a while. Also, you'll get to see deleted posts after you reach 10k reputation points.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995693/wrap-autocompletefield-list-item

Answer (score 1):

I think "calculate the number of lines depending on the row width" means:

- split text on words
- create string array and while words array not empty do

  - create string lineStr
  - while getFont().getAdvance(lineStr+" "+words[i]) < row width move words[i] to lineStr

in the end you will get:

- String[] lines with lines for row
- Row height = lines.lenght * (getFont().getHeight() + topMargin + bottomMargin)