# Wrap AutoCompleteField List Item

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, java-me, word-wrap

My apps has AutoCompleteField that hold long text more than 100 Characters, if I use regular AutoCompleteField I cant read the rest of data.

### [image: Cant read the rest item description]

How can I make the text wrap into 2 or more lines in the autocompletefield options ?
I try using '\r'+'\n' and '\n', its not giving new line. setting it size and also set row height doesnt give me the result I wanted

```
AutoCompleteField autoCustomer = new AutoCompleteField(custList, style);
autoCustomer.getListField().setSize(20);
autoCustomer.getListField().setRowHeight(100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was you I would override `drawListRow` and draw the text using `drawText` which will give me total control on how the row should look. Try adapting your code to behave like this

```
AutoCompleteField autoCompleteField = new AutoCompleteField(
                filterList, AutoCompleteField.LIST_STATIC) {

            public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics g,
                    int index, int y, int width) {

        BasicFilteredListResult result = (BasicFilteredListResult) (autoCompleteField
                .get(listField, index));
        if (result != null) 
        {
                          //Draw text here
        }
            }

            public void onSelect(Object selection, int type) {
                super.onSelect(selection, type);
                if (selection != null) {

                    BasicFilteredListResult result = (BasicFilteredListResult) this
                            .getSelectedObject();
                    handleResult((String) result._object);

                } else {
                    Dialog.alert(Resource
                            .getString(PLEASE_PICK_A_VALID_NAME));
                    return;
                }
            }
        };
```

IF you want to wrap your text you can use the following method

```
// Handy method to wrap text drawn with the specified font into rows with
// the max width
// Found here:
// http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Can-drawText-wrap-text-into-multiple-lines/m-p/499901
public static String[] wrapText(String text, Font f, int maxWidth) {
    Vector result = new Vector();
    if (text == null)
        return new String[] {};

    boolean hasMore = true;

    // The current index of the cursor
    int current = 0;

    // The next line break index
    int lineBreak = -1;

    // The space after line break
    int nextSpace = -1;

    while (hasMore) {
        // Find the line break
        while (true) {
            lineBreak = nextSpace;
            if (lineBreak == text.length() - 1) {
                // We have reached the last line
                hasMore = false;
                break;
            }
            nextSpace = text.indexOf(' ', lineBreak + 1);
            if (nextSpace == -1)
                nextSpace = text.length() - 1;
            int linewidth = f
                    .getAdvance(text, current, nextSpace - current);
            // If too long, break out of the find loop
            if (linewidth > maxWidth)
                break;
        }
        String line = text.substring(current, lineBreak + 1);
        result.addElement(line);
        current = lineBreak + 1;
    }
    String[] resultArray = new String[result.size()];
    result.copyInto(resultArray);
    return resultArray;
}
```

Comment: public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics g,
                    int index, int y, int width)
what is y refer to?, the index seem only index which are now showing, for example its always show 1,2,3 even if the result is more than 3

Comment: y is the Distance from the top of the list field at which to start painting. index is the rowindex which is being displayed